# Access: How to convert 2013 to 2007?

Tags: ms-access-2007, ms-access-2013

I made a form in MS Access 2013, now I want to open same file in 2007.
In "Save as" section I there are options to convert file into Access2000 and Access2002.

Is there any software through which I convert 2013 file into 2007.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

[See Here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/e95dc937-fc8d-49bb-9ab0-847a7394f096/convert-2013-to-2007-access?forum=accessdev)

It seems that there are default settings you can change in MS Access 2013 to allow 2007 conversion. The toughest part would probably be identifying "patches" or "fixes" if you are utilizing MS Access 2013-only features. You can find that list here: [What's new in Access 2013?](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/what-s-new-in-access-2013-HA102809500.aspx)